# Text Between HTML Tags

Tags: c#

I have seen many solutions to things similar to this, but I haven't found a solution yet that works for me.

I already have the source code as a string. I just have one value that I need from the whole page source. I've gotten this to work before with a string like "123", but if I used a my pageSource, it returned nothing. (and yes, there's nothing wrong with the code that returns the source. I have it printing to a textbox just fine)

So for example, my source code is `<div id="test" value="thisisatest">`, I want to return thisisatest.

Also, if someone knows how to do this, if they could also supply a way to print multiple values into a listbox, that'd be nice.

EDIT: I found what I used that didn't work.

```
public string GetSubstringByString(string a, string b, string c)
{
    return c.Substring((c.IndexOf(a) + a.Length), (c.IndexOf(b) - c.IndexOf(a) - a.Length));
}
```

Use (working):

```
string result = GetSubstringByString("1", "3", "123");
MessageBox.Show(result);
```

How I need it to work:

```
string result = GetSubstringByString("1", "3", source);
MessageBox.Show(result);
```

Comment: Please post the code that you have.  It would also be helpful to link to the solutions you found and tell us why they don't work for you.  Otherwise we only have enough information to say to use HTML Agility Pack.

Comment: I deleted my existing code or else I would have posted it. If I find out what I used again, I'll post it.

Comment: Please post the source string and the result string you want. I can't understand what your function is trying to do.

Comment: I want to return the value between (token" style="display: none;">) and (<) Without the parenthesis.

Comment: That code looks like it should work. In principle it's always OK to replace text with a variable that contains text.

Comment: Aha, the problem is that the '<' also appears *before* the first token. You'll need to fix your code to look for the first instance of the second token that's *after* the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that the '<' also appears before the first token. You'll need to fix your code to look for the first instance of the second token that's after the first one. Try this:

```
public string GetSubstringByString(string before, string after, string txt)
{
    int bPos = txt.IndexOf(before);
    int aPos = txt.IndexOf(after,aPos);
    return txt.Substring((bPos + before.Length), (aPos - txt.IndexOf(before) - before.Length));
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! That works perfectly. Now what if there were multiple values that needed to go to a listbox?

Comment: And change the parameter names! Code should be self documenting, so names like a,b,c are horrible.

Comment: To read multiple values, look for the "before" string after the "after" one, and put that in a loop. I'm sure you can figure it out by yourself.

Comment: If the answer works perfectly, perhaps you'd like to accept it?